# Select second largest row by group in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this problem

```
library(dplyr)
problem = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), var1 = c(5,4,3, 6,5,4), var2 = c(99,12,32,88,9,8))
```

For each id, I want to only keep row with second largest value of var1. I tried different ways (dplyr, base R):

```
problem %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_tail(2, -var1)


problem[with(problem, ave(var1, id, FUN = function(x) x == tail(sort(x), 2)[1])), ]
```

First code doesn;t work, second code gives wrong answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no sorting in `slice_tail`, it just uses whatever order the rows are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `arrange`ing the 'var1' on `desc`ending use `slice` with `2`

```
library(dplyr)
problem %>% 
   arrange(id, desc(var1)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(2) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     id  var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    12
2     2     5     9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
problem |> group_by(id) %>% arrange(var1) %>% slice(n()-1)
```

n() counts the number of rows in each group.  slice(n()-1) takes the n-1th element.  Note this will cause issues with groups with fewer than 2 members - you may wish to allow for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use `slice`, I guess you can first `slice_max()` the largest two rows, than `slice_tail` to remove the largest row.

```
library(dplyr)

problem %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(var1, n = 2) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1)
```

Or you can use a single `filter`:

```
problem %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(var1 == max(var1[var1 != max(var1)]))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id  var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    12
2     2     5     9
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have volume, here is a `data.table`approach.

```
problem = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), var1 = c(5,4,3, 6,5,4), var2 = c(99,12,32,88,9,8))
setDT(problem)
setorder(problem, id, - var1)
problem[, .SD[2], by=id]
```

As for @paul Stafford Allen comment, you will have issue for groups of size only 1.